# Spring Security: how can i update/reload usernames and passwords used by inMemoryAuthentication

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm new to Spring and have problems with the inMemoryAuthentication. I set up a very basic Spring MVC app whichs uses Spring Security to authenticate the users. Spring security gets the Username & Password from a HashMap.

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

    Map<String, String> userMap = passwordService.getPasswordMap();
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : userMap.entrySet()) {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser(entry.getKey()).password(entry.getValue()).roles("USER");
    }
}
```

The Problem is, the new Password is only accepted if i restart the app. A simple logout and login doenst work. Here is my logout code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/logout", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String logout(ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (null != auth) {
            new SecurityContextLogoutHandler().logout(request, response, auth);
            request.getSession().invalidate();
        }
```

How can i force the app to reload the information from the HashMap on runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a bean `InMemoryUserDetailsManager`, and inject it to `AuthenticationManagerBuilder`

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(inMemoryUserDetailsManager());
}

@Bean
public InMemoryUserDetailsManager inMemoryUserDetailsManager() {
        // load you user here
        final Properties users = new Properties();
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(users);
}
```

Then you can inject your bean `inMemoryUserDetailsManager` in your service and update the user in `inMemoryUserDetailsManager`.